# Reordering an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of two values ​​and I want to find the element that is equal to the last value of the first element and sort it.
There are many questions/answers dealing with this topic. None match my specific case.

```
var arr = [{'a','b'},{'d','e'},{'b','c'},{'c','d'}];
```

I want it to be sorted again like this, I tried using the sort and localcompare functions, but I couldn't get the right result. I must be missing something.

How can I solve this problem?

```
var arr = [{'a','b'},{'b','c'},{'c','d'},{'d','e'}];
```

Comment: Also share what you have tried till now to solve this

Comment: Your variables are not valid JavaScript and you are not showing what you tried - I feel a little hesitant in writing an algorithm for someone directly, that usually doesn't actually help people. Also, while arrays can be sorted, objects cannot. Why are you doing this to begin with? Is that the data you are working with? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: If there is no matching tuple, should the next one be determined by alphabetic order? So bc,ab,de -> ab,bc,de ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had arrays you could try sorting chars based on their ASCII like the following.

```
let arr = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["d", "e"],
  ["b", "c"],
  ["c", "d"],
];

arr.sort((a, b) => a[1].charCodeAt(0) - b[1].charCodeAt(0));
```